# reg:gamma in a random forest model in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, random-forest

It is known that when building an xgboost model through the `boost_tree()` function, it is possible to introduce a gamma regression through the objective argument of the `set_engine()` function, as seen below:

```
xgbst = boost_tree(
         trees = tune(), 
         tree_depth = tune(),
         min_n = tune(),
         learn_rate = tune(),
         loss_reduction = tune(),
         sample_size = tune()) %>%
set_engine("xgboost", objective = "reg:gamma") %>%
set_mode("regression")
```

However, I am interested in using a random forest model. Therefore, considering that it is possible to introduce arguments in the objective function, I tried to repeat the same computational procedure above, but for random forest, like below:

```
library(randomForest)
library(parsnip)
rfmod = rand_forest(
         trees = tune(),
         mtry = tune(),
         min_n = tune()) %>%
set_engine("randomForest", objective = "reg:gamma") %>%
set_mode("regression")
```

As a result, I am facing an error associated with the fact that it is not possible to introduce Gamma regression in the above model and that there is a bad specification in the computational routine.
In the literature I have already found works that made use of the Gamma distribution in random forest models.

In this case, how could I solve it?

Comment: What error do you get? When I run your code there is no error.

Comment: Please share the exact error you got (not in the comments, edit & update your question accordingly).

Comment: Plus, what is `rand_forest` and where does it come from (it is not part of the `randomForest` package)? Please post a [mre].

Comment: @Quinten, @desertnaut The error I am facing is directly associated with the fact that when I introduce reg:gamma in random forest there is no change in the results when such specification is not present. Is there any way I can introduce a gamma regression using the ````set_engine()```` function but also the hyperparameters through rand_forest()? The ````rand_forest()```` function is from the ````parsnip```` package.

Comment: Again, a reproducible example (as @desertnaut requests) would be best; by lowering the barrier/effort required for someone to test out a potential solution to your problem, you greatly increase the probability of getting a useful reply ...

Comment: Please be **clear** and **specific** in your questions; what you have just clarified is not an *error*! And with this clarification, this is no longer a *programming* question, hence it is off-topic here - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Random Forests(TM) in XGBoost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/rf.html)
follows that you can set the algorithm to fit a randomForest, given the sample_size is less than 1 and you do not do boosting stages:

```
library(parsnip)

xgbst = boost_tree(
         trees = 100, 
         learn_rate = 1,
         sample_size = 0.8) %>%
set_engine("xgboost", objective = "reg:gamma", 
           num_boost_round=1, colsample_bytree=0.8, counts=F) %>%
set_mode("regression")

fit(xgbst, mpg ~ ., data = mtcars, )
```

Comment: Ric Villalba thanks for your answer, but how do I know that the output actually comes from a random forest and not an xgboost?

Answer (score 2):

That method you are looking for is not in the  `rpart` or `randomForest` to my understanding. However there is a package `distRforest` which has a method (function) called `rforest`, within this method you can set a typeof forest to build. One of the options is the Gamma.

`method = 'gamma'`

and you can also use gamma in checking it the out of bag error by setting:

`track_oob=TRUE` when using the `method=gamma`

See if you are able to configure your model that way with [this vignetted as a guide](https://rdrr.io/github/henckr/distRforest/man/rforest.html)